# Using a sorting subroutine from another package

Tags: perl, sorting, package, subroutine

I have a script and a package like so:

```
# file: sortscript.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use SortPackage;

my @arrays = ([1,"array1"],[10,"array3"],[4,"array2"]);

print "Using sort outside package\n";
foreach (sort SortPackage::simplesort @arrays){
    print $_->[1],"\n";
}

print "\nUsing sort in same package\n";
SortPackage::sort_from_same_package(@arrays);
```

--

```
# file: SortPackage.pm
use strict;
use warnings;
package SortPackage;

sub simplesort{
    return ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]);
}

sub sort_from_same_package{
    my @arrs = @_;
    foreach (sort simplesort @arrs){
        print $_->[1],"\n";
    } 
}
1;
```

Running the script produces the output:

```
$ perl sortscript.pl
Using sort outside package
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at SortPackage.pm line 15.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at SortPackage.pm line 15.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at SortPackage.pm line 15.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at SortPackage.pm line 15.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at SortPackage.pm line 15.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at SortPackage.pm line 15.
array1
array3
array2

Using sort in same package
array1
array2
array3
```

Why am I not able to correctly use the subroutine to sort with when it is in another package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been mentioned, `$a` and `$b` are package globals, so another solution is to temporarily alias the globals at the call site to the ones in package `SortPackage`:

```
{
    local (*a, *b) = (*SortPackage::a, *SortPackage::b);
    foreach (sort SortPackage::simplesort @arrays){
        print $_->[1],"\n";
    }
}
```

But this is pretty ugly, of course.  I would just have `SortPackage` export a complete sorting routine, not just a comparator:

```
package SortPackage;
use strict;

sub _sort_by_first_element_comparator {
    return $a->[0] <=> $b->[0];
}

sub sort_by_first_element {
    return sort _sort_by_first_element_comparator @_;
}
```

Comment: Your second solution is what I ended up using yesterday to maintain a package of custom sorting methods. So this is my accepted answer though the other answers are all equally valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`$a` and `$b` are special "package global" variables.

To use the main scope's `$a` and `$b` your comparator function would have to refer to `$::a` or `$main::a` (and likewise for `$b`).

However that comparator function then *wouldn't* work when called from any other package, or even from within its own package.

See the `perlvars` help and the `perldoc` for the `sort` function.  The solution is also in the latter help text:

> If the subroutine’s prototype is `"($$)"`, the elements to be
>                  compared are passed by reference in `@_`, as for a normal
>                  subroutine.  This is slower than unprototyped subroutines,
>                  where the elements to be compared are passed into the
>                  subroutine as the package global variables `$a` and `$b` (see
>                  example below).  Note that in the latter case, it is usually
>                  counter‐productive to declare `$a` and `$b` as lexicals.

Answer (score 5):

The special variables `$a` and `$b` are package globals. Your subroutine expects `$SortPackage::a` and `$SortPackage::b`. When you call it from `sortscript.pl`, the variables `$main::a` and `$main::b` are being set by `sort`.

The solution is to use a prototyped subroutine:

```
package SortPackage;

sub simplesort ($$) {
    return ($_[0]->[0] <=> $_[1]->[0]);
}
```

It's a little slower (since you have actual parameters being passed, instead of reading pre-set globals), but it allows you to use subroutines from other packages by name, as you are attempting.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But perhaps its worth calling the whole sort function from the SortPackage instead, since prototyping may slow things down a little? I hadn't thought of that previously.

Comment: You could. I wouldn't worry about it until you know for a fact that using the prototyped function is actually slowing down your program.